# The size physically occuped by a in the database column depend on my string size or on my column max size?

Tags: postgresql, memory, sqldatatypes

For example, I have a column of varchar(2000) for messages.
If most of my messages have a length of 50 char, the "real place in memory" occupied is optimized?
Or each of them occupies 2000 char?

I use PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage (and memory) space needed only depends on the actual data stored in the column. A column defined as `varchar(2000)` that only contains at most 50 characters, does not need more storage or memory than a column defined as `varchar(50)`

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)

> If the string to be stored is shorter than the declared length, [...] values of type character varying **will simply store the shorter string**

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Note that this is different for the `character` data type - but that [shouldn't be used](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29) anyway